# Add appimage to favourite apps

Tags: gnome, permissions, .desktop, appimage, favorites

I'm trying to add unityhub to my favorites. I have created my .desktop file as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/garrett/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.2f1/Editor/UnityHub
Name=UnityHub
Comment=Description of UnityHub
Icon=/home/garrett/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.2f1/Editor/UnityHub.png
```

saved it as `/usr/share/applications/unityhub.desktop` and set the permissions as executable `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/unityhub.desktop`. The application does not show up in Show Applications (even after logging out and back in). If I retrieve my favorites `dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps` unityhub.desktop is in the array but it does not appear in my dock.

What am I doing wrong here?

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Does the command after `Exec=` work when you execute it at the terminal? As such I see no issues, but some remarks: there is no need to set the desktop file executable, and `/usr/local/share/applications/` is where your custom file belongs.

Comment: @vanadium if I execute `'/home/garrett/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.2f1/Editor/UnityHub.AppImage'` from terminal it launches. Using tutorial here (https://averagelinuxuser.com/ubuntu_custom_launcher_dock/) as a guide. There is no `/usr/local/share/applications/` path on my Ubuntu installation. Today when I rebooted I noticed that the `.desktop` file has a red x icon on it. So I did `sudo chmod 755 /home/garrett/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.2f1/Editor/UnityHub.AppImage`. It's now appearing in my Show Applications and is allowed to be dragged to the dock so problem resolved I think.

Comment: So your "Exec=" line was wrong, thus the .desktop file is not displayed. Command must be valid for a launcher to work.

Comment: @vanadium no I had tried it with and without `.AppImage` as I said and neither worked. It seems to have been the permissions issue that stopped the `.desktop` file from displaying.